# Count number of Hamming distance sequences

Tags: co.combinatorics

Consider all pairs of binary strings $P$ and $T$. Let the length of $P$ be $n$ and the length of $T$ be $2n-1$.  For each such pair, we can compute the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) between $P$ and each of the $n$ substrings of $T$ in order from left to right and output a sequence representing these results. For example:

$$P = 01010, T = 111010011$$

gives an output sequence:

$$4, 1, 4, 2, 3.$$

If we iterate over all possible pairs $P$, $T$ we can count how many distinct sequences we get from the outputs.  For $n = 2, \dots, 8$ we get

- $n = 2$ gives 9
- $n = 3$ gives 48
- $n = 4$ gives 297
- $n = 5$ gives 2040
- $n = 6$ gives 15425
- $n = 7$ gives 125232
- $n = 8$ gives 1070553

This sequence is not on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/).

> Is it possible to give a formula for this count or alternatively to give an asymptotic approximation? In particular, is this number asymptotic to $2^{3n -2}$?

(Previously asked at [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186041/count-number-of-hamming-distance-sequences) with a separate coding focussed question posed on [codegolf.se](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113785/count-the-number-of-hamming-distance-sequences))

Comment: Also posted to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113785/count-the-number-of-hamming-distance-sequences (anywhere else, Lembik?).

Comment: [Related question in Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177922/a-communication-complexity-problem-for-finding-near-matches). It was also posted in MO but that apparently has been deleted by the author.

Comment: This is a very nice question. We know a lower bound of $2^{n-1}$ by setting $P$ to all zeros and the last $n-1$ bits of $T$ to all zeros as well.  In this case the output tells you exactly what the first $n-1$ bits are.   Maybe someone can see how to get a higher lower bound?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't expect there to be much overlap between codegolf answers which are designed to be coding competitions often testing out people's favourite programming languages and mathoverflow ones.

Comment: @Anush, it's a matter of common courtesy that when you post a question to two (or more!) places you let each place know about all the others.